# VirtualBox で同一のovaファイルを再インポートできる方法はないでしょうか

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Windows 10 上にインストールした VirtualBox で、ovaファイルをインポートしてゲストOSを作成しました。

一度除去したあと、同じovaファイルをインポートしようとすると、以前の設定ファイルが残っていてインポートが失敗になります。

ovaファイルでインポートしたいInter-Mediator serverの他とのバージョン互換性を保つために、除去したのと同じovaファイルを再度インポートする必要があり、何か方法があれば教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0):

仮想マシンの除去を行う際、「一覧からの削除のみ」か「設定ファイルを含めて削除」かを選ぶはずですが、今回は恐らく前者を選んで実行したため、仮想マシンの設定ファイルが残った状態なのだと思われます。

#### 仮想マシンの削除方法

- まずは VirtualBox の「環境設定」から、デフォルトの仮想マシンの保存先を確認しておいてください。
- 確認後、念の為 VirtualBox はいったん終了しておきます。
- 確認したフォルダをエクスプローラで開くと仮想マシンごとのフォルダが存在するはずなので、その中から不要なフォルダを (フォルダごと) 削除してみてください。

Comment: VirtualBoxごと再インストールし、除去後に残っていた仮想マシンのフォルダを削除してやってみると、うまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: もし解決したようであれば、回答を承認していただけると幸いです。 - 参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)